# Set attributesToGet() in ListUsersRequest : Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I want to fetch only username attribute from cognito.

When I do not set anything in my attributesToGet(), I am able to successfully fetch the record. But when I try to set any attributes, I get an error :
**AwsErrorDetails(errorMessage=One or more requested attributes do not exist., errorCode=InvalidParameterException, serviceName=CognitoIdentityProvider)**

below is the code with the attribute set to username

```
 String emailId = "xyz@gmail.com";
 ListUsersRequest listUsersRequest = ListUsersRequest.builder()
            .userPoolId(userPoolId)
            .filter(String.format("%s = \"%s\"", "email", emailId))
            .attributesToGet(new String[]{"username"})
            .build();

        ListUsersResponse userInfo = cognitoIdentityProviderClient
            .listUsers(listUsersRequest);
```

below is a screenshot of my cognito pool headers
[image]

Please help me get this working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute `username` you are trying to get is not part of the list of attributes for which this is applicable, it is a "top-level" user attribute and is always present.

When you get a response (as you are able to when not passing anything in `attributesToGet`) you will notice the attributes list does not contain the username, which is outside, as seen in this example:

```json
{
  "Users": [
    {
      "Username": "johndoe",
      "Attributes": [
        { "Name": "sub", "Value": "41f3c652-6d3b-4ae5-8bad-271785f9adb5" },
        { "Name": "email_verified", "Value": "true" },
        { "Name": "name", "Value": "John Doe" },
        { "Name": "email", "Value": "johndoe@example.org" },
        { "Name": "custom:role", "Value": "administrator" }
      ],
      "UserCreateDate": "2022-06-22T11:11:40.180000+01:00",
      "UserLastModifiedDate": "2022-07-23T11:55:35.352000+01:00",
      "Enabled": true,
      "UserStatus": "RESET_REQUIRED"
    }
  ]
}
```

Also check the [ListUsers Response syntax in API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html#API_ListUsers_ResponseSyntax) where the Username is shown as a top-level field.